# Unix: How to send Mime files as mails

Tags: email, unix, sendmail, mime

I have a program that outputs MIME formatted files. I need to send these from an unix machine.

The files have the format as such:

```
From: ******
To: ******
Message-ID: ******
Subject: ******
MIME-Version: ******
Content-Type: ******
Content-Transfer-Encoding: ******

<PAYLOAD>
```

Is there a way to specify such a file (Preferably without specifying any other information than the file) through a native unix command, such as sendmail?

Comment: Does `sendmail -ba -t < /path/to/message.msg` not work?

Comment: `sendmail -i -t < /path/to/message.msg`should be better